# intellij - No code-completion for JSF2 @Named annotated bean

Tags: jsf-2, autocomplete, intellij-idea, javabeans, cdi

IntelliJ doesn't seem to recognize my JSF2 managed beans when I annotate them with `@Named`, the CDI (JSR299) annotation used when deploying your web application on a Glassfish server.

```
@Named("userBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String password;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I don't get any auto-completion when using the bean in an EL expression (e.g. `#{userBean.name}`). And when I open the JSF-tab in IntelliJ, there are no Managed Beans listed. When I use the `@ManagedBean` annotation, I do get auto-completion + my beans are listed in the JSF tab. Do I have to configure something or how do I get this working?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VDhz.png

Comment: Have you tried `Right-Click Project > Add Framework Support > CDI`? Works just fine in mine after I do that. Also look into http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/context-and-dependency-injection-(cdi).html and http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/jsf.html

Comment: @rdcrng Great, it works now! I didn't know there was a CDI plugin in IntelliJ, which I had to activate in Settings > Plugins, then I was able to "Add Framework Support" for CDI. Thanks! If you post your solution, I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `Right-Click Project > Add Framework Support > CDI`? Also look into [IntelliJ CDI Docs](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/context-and-dependency-injection-%28cdi%29.html) and [IntelliJ JSF Docs](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/jsf.html).

Comment: Great, but first link is broken!